# A specific sequence such that there is no three-term arithmetic progression in the sequence: does the corresponding series of reciprocals diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, convergence-divergence, arithmetic-progressions

Define the sequence of natural numbers $(a_n)_n$ recursively as follows:

For each $k\geq 0,\ $ define $a_{k+1}$ to be the least natural number such that it doesn't make a three term arithmetic progression with (two) previous terms in the sequence.

So if I haven't made a mistake, this sequence is: $1,2,4,5,10,11,13,14,28,29, 31, 32, 37, 38, 40, 41,\ldots.$

My question is, does $\sum \frac{1}{a_k}$ converge or diverge?

I believe this question is related to [Erdos' conjecture on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions), which I have been reading about.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A003278

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks for that link. I don't see an answer to my question on that page though...

Comment: @AdamRubinson [Converges](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.03528)

Comment: @AdamRubinson An easier answer to your question is that $\sum \frac{1}{a_k}$ (super) converges since $\{a_k\}_k$ is the set of positive integers without a $0$ in their base $3$ representation, which, by basic combinatorics/probability, is an exponentially small set.

Comment: @mathworker21 thanks for that link. I'm not sure I fully get your last comment (although I have *some* idea - I'm just not used to working in other bases than $10$ to be honest). It would need to be expanded on with examples for me to fully get it.

Comment: Might converge to something like $3.0079\ldots$

Comment: @AdamRubinson The set $\{0,1,\dots,3^n-1\}$ is in bijection with $\{0,1,2\}^n$, i.e., strings of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{0,1,2\}$, via base-$3$ expansion. So the number of non-negative integers less than $3^n$ without a $0$ in their base-$3$ expansion is equal to $2^n$, which is $(3^n)^{\log_2 3}$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson:  it is positional notation in base $3$.  So, for example, $127_{10}=81+27+2\cdot 9 +1=1\cdot 3^4+1 \cdot 3^3+2\cdot 3^2+0\cdot 3 +1 \cdot 3^0=11201_3$  Because there is a $0$ in the base $3$ expansion, $127$ is not in the set.  In fact, $127=122+5$  But the comment in OEIS says you subtract $1$ from the number and the expansion should not have any $2$s.  So $10=101_3$ is a member despite the $0$, but $10-1=9=100_3$ contains no $2$s

Comment: @RossMillikan what is the reason that the base $3$ representation of one less than any number in the sequence contains no $2$s? Also, I'm confused by previous comments about members of the sequence containing no $0$s base $3.$ This is surely not true as Ross Milikan has pointed out: e.g. $10 = 101_{3}.$

Comment: I was just echoing a comment in the OEIS entry about the base $3$ representation.  I don't know how to prove it.  The comment about no $0$s in the representation is wrong.

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, $a_n$ grows roughly as $n^\alpha$ where $\alpha = \log_2(3) \approx 1.585$.  Since $\alpha > 1$, $\sum_n 1/a_n$ converges.

Comment: it's easy to prove that growth rate by noting what exactly the $a_n$'s are (see comments).